# See if User's Coordinates have Changed

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am trying to figure out the most efficient way to check whether a user has moved after a certain period of time (for example 15 minutes).

If they have not moved more than 200 ft, I would then like to display an alert that says "you have been here for 15 minutes."

I know enabling background location services will eat up the battery, so I would like to check the user's location every 5 minutes or so. Is there a clean way to do this without destroying the user's battery? I don't really know where to begin. Any assistance would be wonderful!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just use a repeating `NSTimer` that fires at your desired interval & retrieves the location. Then compare it against the previous recorded location. Polling for the location every 5 minutes or so is not going to have a massively detrimental impact on power consumption.